# Spinner object reference problem?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

How to use if else statement when using spinner objects?

I wish to [make a page like this](https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.avdheshyadav.android.dmfarechart/ss-0-320-480-160-1-1419b41ab151cbd3897b7984d750b5727710fa36) in Android.

I have done the coding for the button and the spinners and I have used an array to store the values in the spinner.

**My Problem**: When I select some values in both the spinners and click on "SHOW FARE" button the fare is not generated??

```
public class HelloSpinner extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
     * @return */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.source_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.destination_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

        View v= findViewById(R.id.button);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()=="Adarsh Nagar"
           && spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()=="Rajiv Chowk")
           {
                TextView t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
                t.setText("Fare:Rs. 16");
           }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:

        Intent i = new Intent(this,Fare.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;  
        }
        }
   }
```

If anyone can spot error(s) in the code, I would appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Create setOnItemSelectedListener for both spinner and inside that store the selected Value in a string Variable..

After that in Button click Check you if Conditions..

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 selectedspinnervalue =s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

where the string variable selectedspinnervalue contains the value selected by the spinner..

Now in the Button Click check the condition like this :

```
yourbuttonobject.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if(selectedvalueinspinner.equalsIgnoreCase("Adarsh Nagar")&& selectedvalueinspinner1.equalsIgnoreCase("Rajiv Chowk")){
                // Your desired Code..
            } 
        }
    });
```